# Make normal mode the default mode for zsh when vim keys have been set

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I have set

```
bindkey -v
```

in my `~/.zshrc` so that `vim` keybindings are created whenever I open  `zsh`. Because of that, `viins` (a.k.a insert mode) is the keymap with which a new instance of `zsh` starts. I would like to make the `vicmd` keymap (a.k.a. normal mode) the one with which `zsh` starts.

This is what I've got so far

**1)** [This is the part of the `zsh` documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps) that discusses about keymaps and how you can create new keymaps.

**2)** I found [a post in a forum](https://zsh-users.zsh.narkive.com/MJFm7kIq/why-can-t-the-main-keymap-be-an-alias-from-vicmd) in which what it seems to be a `zsh` developer answer a question similar to mine and he explains why accomplishing what I'm requesting isn't trivial.

**3)** The `vi-cmd-mode` is the editor function in `viins` keymap that switch to the `vicmd` keymap (see below)

```
$ bindkey -v && bindkey | grep '"\^\["'
"^[" vi-cmd-mode
```

Because of this, I could also accomplish what I'm requesting if I were able to call an editor function (which in this case is `vi-cmd-mode`) whenever a new `zsh` instance is opened. Perhaps, there is a way to call an editor function by writing something in my `zshrc`. Thus `zsh` will start in `viins` but immediately switch to `vicmd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first answer to the forum post you linked points to an example in the documentation from the `zshzle(1)` man page that probably achieves what you want. The second, longer answer goes into technical details of linking the `main` keymap to `vicmd` which, while closer to the precise question asked in the forum, is not exactly useful. So you may want to try the following:

```
zle-line-init() { zle -K vicmd; }
zle -N zle-line-init
```

Also, if you use the `vared` builtin you can force that to start in the `vicmd` keymap with:

```
alias vared='vared -i vi-cmd-mode'
```